# How to make an ajax call asynchronous?

Tags: ajax, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I was trying to retrieve CRM records using Ajax calls.

```
function RetrieveCrmRecords(entName, fields, filter, callback, orderby, errcallback) {
    ///<summary>
    /// function to Retrieve Multiple CRM records.
    ///</summary>
    //debugger;
    var async = !!callback;

    var setEntityName = entName + 'Set';
    var _callback = callback;

    filter = (filter) ? "&$filter=" + filter : '';

    var query1 = CrmServerUrl + ODATA + "/";
    var query2 = setEntityName + "()" + "?";
    var queryUrl = query1 + query2;

    if (fields != null) queryUrl += "$select=" + fields.join(',');
    if (orderby != null) {
        if (fields != null) {
            queryUrl += '&';
        }
        queryUrl += "$orderby=" + orderby;
    }
    queryUrl += filter;

    var performRequest = function (queryUrl, fnCallback) {
        var async = !!fnCallback;
        var opts = { url: queryUrl }

        return _makeRequest(opts, async, function (data) {
            var nextData = data.__next || null;
            var resultsData = data.results || data;
            var responseData = { 'results': resultsData, 'next': nextData }

            if (nextData) {
                responseData.LoadNext = function (callback) {
                    return performRequest(nextData, callback);
                };
            }

            if (async) {
                fnCallback(responseData);
            }
            else {
                return responseData;
            }
        }, errcallback);
    };

    return performRequest(queryUrl, callback);
}
```

As I don't have that much idea about ajax calls, its hard to make this function Asynchronous for me.

Experts please help me to understand that this function is synchronous because of   `var async = !!callback;` this?

If in place of this line I write `var async=true;` can it make this function asynchronous?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got you exactly what you are asking for.

Please don't get look into this file from where you have copied and pasted this function.
This will make you confuse if you are new for this.

Just call the function from your .js File like this.

```
function RetrieveCrmRecords(entName, fields, filter, calledForAsync, orderby, errcallback) {
//Your Code
}

function calledForAsync()
{
//Your Code
}
```

When Operation in RetrieveCrmRecords() will completed rest code will execute finely and then it will come into the calledForAsync().

This is called Async Call.
I hope you were asking for this.

Thanks,

Anish.